# Instance of OWL-class with unionOf (n3)

Tags: instance, owl, restriction, n3

Suppose i have an OWL-class as following:

```
:picture    rdf:type owl:Class ;
            owl:unionOf(:creator :theme :title :date) .
```

With `:creator`, `:theme`, `:title` and `:date` either an `owl:ObjectProperty` or `owl:DataProperty`.

For example:

```
:creator    rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:comment "The creator of this picture." ;
            rdfs:domain :picture ;
            rdfs:range foaf:Person .
```

How can i create an instance of this picture class ?

(I understand how i create an instance of an easy thing such as : `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Paris>  rdf:type :location .` would be an instance of a location)

Comment: You can't, because your class definition is not valid OWL. You can not use a `owl:unionOf` constraint with a list of properties (the values can only be class descriptions). Can you describe what you are trying to model, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to describe the class which **may** contain properties `:creator`, `:theme`, `:title`, and `:date` you should just describe the domain for all properties (no additional definitions in picture class are necessary):

```
:picture a owl:Class .

:creator rdfs:domain :picture ;
         rdfs:range foaf:Person .
```

And so on.

If you want to describe the class which **must** contain these properties, cardinality constraints should be added:

```
:picture a owl:Class ;
         rdfs:subClassOf [
             a owl:Restriction ;
             owl:onProperty creator ;
             owl:minCardinality "1"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
         ]
         rdfs:subClassOf [
             a owl:Restriction ;
             owl:onProperty theme ;
             owl:cardinality "1"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
         ]
         ... etc ...
```

In both cases the definition of an instance looks like following:

```
:monaLisa a :picture ;
          :creator :LeonardoDaVinci ;
          ...
          :date "1503-01-01"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>
```

More about restriction you can learn, for example, from [this](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~guus/public/owl-restrictions/#h3-qcr) document.